# How to add a minimum margin-top?

Tags: html, css, margin

i would like to have a sort of minimum margin-top. Basically if you visit my webpage
[NerdyFuture](http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com/). And scale the browser window down, the carousel will get smaller that's why the last news header and box need to go up. But at some point I want it to stop going up, so that the box doesn't overlap the carousel. How can i do this? Is there some kind of hack for this?

Latest News Header:

```
#latest_news_header{
z-index:3;
position:relative;
    float:left;
width:100%;
min-width: 613px;
max-width:45%;
display:inline;
margin-top:23.5%;
font-size: 1.0em;
text-align:left;
background-color:#828282;
margin-left:18.6%;
font-weight:400;
padding:3px;
font-family: Proxima-Nova,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;   
color:#30DB00;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
```

Latest News Box:

```
.latest_news_box{ 
z-index:2;
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:left;
width:100%;
margin-left:18.6%;
min-width: 619px;
max-width:44.9vw;
height:600px;
background-color:white;
```

}

Comment: Need the HTML and css

Comment: IMHO just looking at your site and the css in chrome dev tools , I would have done it a little different where I have a container div that has the slideshow part and your latest news div. That way I wont have to use relative positioning. But that is just me.

Comment: that the code of the header and the box

Comment: all roads lead to Rome right,hahah

Comment: I agree with @Sai on this one. I think you need to rework how you have the page laid out. Trying putting them in separate DIVs so they don't overlap at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Header_CSS.css line 35 you have :

```
#header {
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
background-color: #828282;
max-height: 46px;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

remove the

```
max-height: 46px;
```

and give your `#latest_news_header` a margin-top of something like 10px, or whatever you feel is right.